# Finding index of a cell containing a value and highlighting all those cells in QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qstring

How can we find out the index (i.e both row and column numbers) of a cell containing a QString in a QTableView using QT c++?

(P.S.:Without clicking on the cell in qtableview)

Comment: You mean search and find value in table  ?

Comment: After searching i want the position of the value in the table

Comment: I update my answer. this line added: `((QStandardItemModel*)modelIndex.model())->item(modelIndex.row(),index)->setData(QBrush(Qt::green),Qt::BackgroundRole);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `findItems()` function to find your cell.

`findItems()` function returns a list of items that match the given text, using the given flags, in the given column.

```
for (int index = 0; index < model->columnCount(); index++)
{
    QList<QStandardItem*> foundLst = model->findItems("YourText", Qt::MatchExactly, index);
}
```

If you want to get index of found item and highlight it use this code:

```
for (int index = 0; index < model->columnCount(); index++)
{
    QList<QStandardItem*> foundLst = model->findItems("YourText", Qt::MatchExactly, index); 
    int count = foundLst.count();
    if(count>0)
    {
            for(int k=0; k<count; k++)
            {
                 QModelIndex modelIndex = model->indexFromItem(foundLst[k]);
                 qDebug()<< "column= " << index << "row=" << modelIndex.row();
                ((QStandardItemModel*)modelIndex.model())->item(modelIndex.row(),index)->setData(QBrush(Qt::green),Qt::BackgroundRole);
            }
    }
}
```

More info:

[QTableView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtableview.html): The `QTableView` class provides a default model/view implementation of a table view.

[QStandardItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html): The `QStandardItemModel` class provides a generic model for storing custom data.