# Highlight specific rows in qtableview in qt

Tags: qt, highlight, qtableview

The below code returns the indexes of certain qtableview rows containing same data. I want to highlight such rows. How do I do so?

```
 @
    for (int index = 0; index < model->columnCount(); index++)
    {
        QList<QStandardItem*> foundLst = model->findItems("YourText", 
        Qt::MatchExactly, index); 
        int count = foundLst.count();
        if(count>0)
        {
                for(k=0; k<count; k++)
                {
                     QModelIndex modelIndex = model->indexFromItem(foundLst[k]);
                     qDebug()<< "column= " << index << "row=" << modelIndex.row();
                }
        }
    }
    @
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45543721/finding-index-of-a-cell-containing-a-value-and-highlighting-all-those-cells-in-q/45545259#45545259

Answer (score 0):

`foundLst[k]->setData( ... )`; whatever you want from `Qt::BackgroundRole`, `Qt::TextColorRole` and so on;

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum